# Intellij Idea not able to execute git pre-push hook

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, githooks, intellij-plugin

I would like to execute a git pre-push hook from the IntelliJ IDEA.
Git pre-push hook can able to execute via a Terminal but not from the IntelliJ IDEA.

I have posted the Version Control console: 
[image]
And Its saying `JAVA_HOME` is not set.

#### Used Versions

```
Java : 1.8.0_211
IntelliJ IDEA : IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 EAP (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-192.4787.16
Ubuntu : 18.04
Git : 2.17.1
```

#### Git pre-push hook script

```
source ~/.bash_profile
remote="$1"
url="$2"
echo “Running Tests”
pwd
./gradlew test
exit $?
```

I am not getting the where is a problem exactly and How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is no JAVA_HOME variable defined in the environment the hook is run in. The environment is inherited from the parent process, so depending on how and when IntelliJ is started, its environemnt

The easiest way to fix the issue is to define JAVA_HOME in the hook itself (or maybe in .bash_profile), e.g. by adding `export JAVA_HOME=<PATH to your Java Home>` in it. This way variable will be set during hook execution and gradlew will not fail.

Comment: What I think is, `source ~/.bash_profile` would do this thing for me.

Comment: If there is explicit export in the .bash_profile, and it is not overriden somewhere else, sourcing it should help. However, from the errror message it seems it does not work. at the moment.